# if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, html

I got this code, in login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>login.php</title>
<charset="utf8" />

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    echo "It works!";
}
?>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Log in:</h1>
<form method="POST" action="login.php" autocomplete="off">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required="required" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" required="required" /> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a php beginner, and I am trying to post data to the same page. After testing I discovered that the php did execute, but didn't echo "It works".

Any help for this is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have printed the text in the head..

You should give the echo statement inside the body tag.Your code supposed to look like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>login.php</title>
<meta charset="utf8" />
</head>

<body>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  echo "It works!";
}
?>

<h1>Log in:</h1>
<form method="POST" action="login.php" autocomplete="off">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required="required" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" required="required" /> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```